# How to customize the Strapi Admin Panel

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm setting up a new website with Strapi 3.0.0-beta as the backend. Following the docs, I've managed to change the logo and the background-color. What I can't seem to do is add a config.js file to remove the information box containing the tutorial videos.

I've tried doing exactly what is written in the docs, that is, adding a config.js file to ./admin/src/config.js

Here is the code I put in the file :

```
export const SHOW_TUTORIALS = false;
```

I expect this to, after executing npm run build, modify the admin panel to remove the tutorial video box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the information in the docs is correct. I had to upgrade to 3.0.0-beta.16 for it to work (I was using 3.0.0-beta.15).